# In Java, how do I write a recursive method that checks whether or not a B-Tree is binary (every child node has no more than 2 children)?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, logic, b-tree

This is what I tried, but it always returns false. Maybe my B-Tree is bad, but how do I solve this?

Both of these methods are in the BTree class, therefore root is the starting node.

I assumed that it is not necessary to check whether or not any possible children are null, since only the length of the children array matters.

```
public boolean isBinary() {
    return isBinary(root);
}

private boolean isBinary(BNode node) {
    if (node.children.length != 2)
        return false;
    else
        return (true && isBinary(node.children[0]) && isBinary(node.children[1]));
            
}
```

Comment: One reasonable implementation of a B-tree node is a fixed-size array of references, some of which may be null. That fixed size would not be two, which would cause your method to always return false. 

By the way, consider whether `(true && X)` would differ from simply `X`.

Comment: How are the leafs in this tree?

Answer (score 0):

Your function could only return true if the tree would have no leaf-nodes. B-Trees obviously have leaves.

Your `(node.children.length != 2)` condition suggests that you are working with dynamically sized `children` arrays, so I'll assume that when there are no children, the `children.length` is zero.

So change to this:

```
private boolean isBinary(BNode node) {
    if (node.children.length == 0)
        return true; // Leaves are OK.
    if (node.children.length != 2)
        return false;
    else
        return (isBinary(node.children[0]) && isBinary(node.children[1]));
}
```

Of course, if you have a different way to identify leaves, like with a different class that does not have a `children` field, then test for that condition instead. The essence is that you should detect when you are at a leaf and then always return true.

Comment: I thought that even the leaf-nodes have the children array, and that it's merely filled with null (until nodes are put into it, at which point it is no longer a leaf).
Could you explain what the effect of "if (node.children.length == 0)" would be therefore?
Is an array with nulls considered an array of length 0? Or is there not even an array in the leaf-nodes to begin with (and instead, simply "null" instead of a null-filled array)?

Comment: There are several ways to encode a B-Tree. From your condition `(node.children.length != 2)` I took that you work with dynamically sized arrays (otherwise this condition is useless), and then it would make sense that in a leaf node the `length` is zero. The essence of my answer is that you must detect whether you are at a leaf node. If in your question you could add the actual class definition(s) you use, and the way you identify a leaf, then I can adapt my answer to that, but the principle remains the same: return true whenever you are at a leaf.